# app crashes when switching to tab

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar controller with two tabs and normally I can move normally between the tabs but there is one point in which I select the second tab and the app crashes in te logs it only shows lldb if I write `bt` it gives me the following

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x5dc59, 0x0061b0b2 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 14, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1000000c)
frame #0: 0x0061b0b2 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 14
frame #1: 0x0134e10c UIKit`-[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 102
frame #2: 0x0061d7cd libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
frame #3: 0x0119ba40 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 99
frame #4: 0x0119b9d2 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
frame #5: 0x014f66fd UIKit`-[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 466
frame #6: 0x0061d7cd libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
frame #7: 0x0119ba40 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 99
frame #8: 0x0119b9d2 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
frame #9: 0x012dc13a UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 69
frame #10: 0x012dc557 UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 598
frame #11: 0x012dc172 UIKit`-[UIControl sendActionsForControlEvents:] + 48
frame #12: 0x014fb690 UIKit`-[UITabBar(Static) _buttonUp:] + 123
frame #13: 0x0061d7cd libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
frame #14: 0x0119ba40 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 99
frame #15: 0x0119b9d2 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
frame #16: 0x012dc13a UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 69
frame #17: 0x012dc557 UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 598
frame #18: 0x012db7c1 UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 660
frame #19: 0x011f3caa UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 874
frame #20: 0x011f4786 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 792
frame #21: 0x011b2681 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
frame #22: 0x011c2ab8 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 21484
frame #23: 0x011962e7 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2300
frame #24: 0x008a006f CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
frame #25: 0x00895b7d CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
frame #26: 0x008950d8 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 952
frame #27: 0x00894a5b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
frame #28: 0x0089488b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #29: 0x04bab2c9 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 192
frame #30: 0x04bab106 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
frame #31: 0x0119a0b6 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1526
* frame #32: 0x00072624 PIBA`main + 180 at AppDelegate.swift:12
    frame #33: 0x03526ac9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

From what I can understand is that it is indeed crashing when switching from tab but why?

I enabled NS Zombies and it printed

```
 *** -[PIBA.PreguntasViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7ae2dea0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no this now about  switching the tab but this deallocated instance   means some of the instance you are trying to access its not on the stage (memory) right now or its removed from memory address. so definitely you cannot access any thing which is not present over there wheres you looking  for  hope you understand  if you have any confusion  ask me

Comment: How can I debug it? How can I know where and why it is being removed from memory?

Comment: check the the selector or responder you are calling here either  create exception breaking point check this
url  http://oramind.com/182-ios-5-xcode-backtrace/

Comment: if you  understand what  told you and its  working for you  please accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation. In my case this message had place because of array stack overflow. This solution helped me to debug the error:

1. Make sure that you have this option "Debug->Debug Workflow->Always Show Disassembly" not checked
2. And allow this: Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme, Run->Diagnostics-> Address Sanitizer.

After that it will show overflows in your code and you will be able to fix that.

P.S.: But I was confused too, why an error in application logic appears only when a tab is switching...